# efficient way to get latest data using MAX()

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which stores the exchange rates of currencies on a given day (`TBAADM.EXC`). However the exchange rates are manually entered, and the erroneous rate entered previously has to be archived, so the table can end up having multiple entries of a given from-to exchange rate per day because of user error or because the exchange rate has changed during the day. To do this, I have a column in the table called `UPDATE_NO` which indicates that a given entry is the nth entry for the day. For example, the first exchange rate entry for the day will have an `UPDATE_NO` value of `001`. If the exchange rate has changed or was entered incorrectly, the next entry will have a value of `002`, and so on.

What I need to do now, is to get the latest entry of a from-to exchange rate for a given day:

```
select exc_rate
from tbaadm.exc
    where bank_id = 'BANK01'
    and designation = 'REV'
    and fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
    and to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
    and rtlist_date = '10-AUG-2015'
    and update_no = --maximum
```

This is what I currently have, but I think this would definitely affect the runtime of my script since I traverse the `EXC` table twice per record:

```
select exc_rate
    from tbaadm.exc
    where bank_id = 'BANK01'
    and designation = 'REV'
    and fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
    and to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
    and rtlist_date = '10-AUG-2015'
    and update_no = (select max(update_no) from tbaadm.exc
        where bank_id = 'BANK01'
        and designation = 'REV'
        and fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
        and to_crncy_code = 'PHP' 
        and rtlist_date = '10-AUG-2015')
```

Is there a more efficient way to utilize the MAX() function? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are in the same session you could use a sequence to make this process work. You update your `update_no` with the sequence value `sequenceName.NEXTVAL` and then just use on your `select` `update_no =sequenceName.CURRVAL` which will be the last (max) update number

Answer (score 1):

> Just adding we can also use Analytical functions with KEEP function to
>   restrict the output in the query itself. No need to go via INLINE view
>   by this and performance wise its better. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT DISTINCT exc_rate,
MAX(update_no) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
ORDER BY update_no) OVER (PARTITION BY bank_id,designation,fr_crncy_code,to_crncy_code,rtlist_date) "Max dt"
FROM tbaadm.exc
WHERE bank_id     = 'BANK01'
AND designation   = 'REV'
AND fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
AND to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
AND rtlist_date   = '10-AUG-2015' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select exc_rate
from (
select exc_rate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY update_no DESC) rnk
    from tbaadm.exc
    where bank_id = 'BANK01'
    and designation = 'REV'
    and fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
    and to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
    and rtlist_date = '10-AUG-2015'

) i
where i.rnk = 1
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

update:

```
select exc_rate
from (
select exc_rate
    , fr_crncy_code
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY update_no DESC) rnk
    from tbaadm.exc
    where bank_id = 'BANK01'
    and designation = 'REV'
    and to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
    and rtlist_date = '10-AUG-2015'

) i
where i.rnk = 1
    AND fr_crncy_code = 'usd'
```

Comment: how about if I want to make some of the conditions (i.e. `fr_crncy_code`) to be compared to a superquery (`fr_crncy_code = cq.crncy_code`) ? I tried but it says `table or view does not exist`.

Comment: @JamesP Then in the subquery you select fr_crncy_code without the where and use a where on the outer select. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I added some changes to Avrajit Roy's script:

```
SELECT MAX(exc_rate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY update_no) as needed_rate
FROM tbaadm.exc
WHERE bank_id     = 'BANK01'
AND designation   = 'REV'
AND fr_crncy_code = 'USD'
AND to_crncy_code = 'PHP'
AND rtlist_date   = '10-AUG-2015' ;
```

If you will need find last rates for all groups, add *group by* clause